# Questions about books about fantasy books on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm currently reading *The Lord of the Rings:  A Reader's Companion* by Wayne Hammond and Christina Scull, and I was wondering if questions related to this book, which is obviously about LotR, would be considered "on topic".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As this is a non-fiction book about a fantasy universe, questions about the **subject matter** ("why does Wayne Hammond think this") probably would be on topic.

By comparison, questions about the book itself or the author would probably be off-topic.

Per my normal advice, why not visit the chatroom and pre-ask the question?

Answer (score 12):

Books like this would fall under one or both of these entries in our [site's scope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- Historical or societal context of a work
- Behind-the-scenes and fandom information

So I'd expect most questions on these sorts of books about fantasy (or sci-fi!) works to be on topic, as their focus would overlap with these areas.